how to merge data from RTK Query
I have paged data from my server that I'd like to display in an endless scroll. I know I can manage it with pure redux, but I'd like to be able to do it with Redux Toolkit. I've tried reading https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1163?sort=new, but I don't understand the way people have done this. RTK's merge seems the most promising option https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#merge but so far my implementation just overwrites the existing data with the new page rather than appending it.
The code as per the merge example in the official documentation:
            query: ({accountId, page}) => {
                console.log('accountId', accountId);
                return {
                    url: `/api/transactions/account/${accountId}`,
                    method: 'get',
                    params: {page}
                }
            },
            serializeQueryArgs: ({endpointName}) => {
                return endpointName
            },
            merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
              currentCache.push(...newItems)
            },
            forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg}) {
                return currentArg !== previousArg;
            },
        }),

gives me an error TypeError: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function for currentCache.push(...newItems)
I've swapped this out for return [...currentCache, ...newItems], but this tells me that TypeError: currentCache is not iterable
What should I try next? The data is in response.data.data, which might be confusing things a bit. I'd also want access to response.data.last_page so I know when to stop fetching data.

It was a matter of trial and error since I could never see the value of currentCache, but I realised that I needed to add response.data.data to the currentCache. In the end, the following worked.
currentCache.data.push(...newItems.data);

My final code is:
export const transactionsSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: build => ({
        getTransactions: build.query({
            query: ({accountId, page}) => {
                return {
                    url: `/api/transactions/account/${accountId}`,
                    method: 'get',
                    params: {page}
                }
            },
            serializeQueryArgs: ({endpointName}) => {
                return endpointName
            },
            merge: (currentCache, newItems, { arg }) => {
                const { page } = arg;

                // this check deletes all transactions when account changes
                if (page === 1) {
                    return newItems;
                }

                // more complex update to replace existing data if required
                const updatedData = [
                    ...currentCache.data.filter(existingItem => !newItems.data.some(newItem => newItem.trans_id === existingItem.trans_id)),
                    ...newItems.data,
                ];
                return {
                    data: updatedData,
                    current_page: newItems.current_page,
                    last_page: newItems.last_page,
                };
            },
            forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg}) {
                return currentArg !== previousArg;
            },
            providesTags: (result = [], error, arg) => [
                'Transaction',
                ...(result.data ? result.data.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Transaction', id })) : []),
            ],
        }),
        deleteTransaction: build.mutation({
            query: (transactionId) => {
                return {
                    url: `/api/transactions/${transactionId}/delete`,
                    method: 'patch',
                }
            },

            // update cache to reflect deleted transaction
            async onQueryStarted(transactionId, { dispatch, queryFulfilled}) {
                const patchResult = dispatch(
                    transactionsSlice.util.updateQueryData('getTransactions', transactionId, (draft) => {
                        const transactionToUpdate = draft.data.find(transaction => transaction.trans_id === transactionId);
                        transactionToUpdate.deleted = 1;
                    })
                )
                queryFulfilled.catch(patchResult.undo);
            },
            invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
                { type: 'Account' }
            ],
        }),
    })
})

Note that I've included provision and invalidation of tags because in my project there is some interaction between Account and Transaction, but this isn't core to getting pagination working with RTK.

While this answered my immediate problem, I'm going to go back to managing the data myself in plain redux because I couldn't manage changes properly. If I update an item from the most recent page, then forceRefetch would refresh that page, but if I updated an item from an earlier page, I never managed to refresh the appropriate page.

Further update: After a bit more research, I found that you can manually update the cached data so that it matches the server updates without having to refetch the data. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates This worked perfectly for my needs.  I'll update my answer with the full code.

I assume, you need to make sure currentCache is always an array while performing a spreading operation. you can ensure that currentCache by doing :
merge: (currentCache = [], newItems) => [...currentCache, ...newItems],

Additionally, to access response.data.last_page and stop fetching data when needed, you might need to adjust your logic outside of the merge function. You can check the value of last_page in your component or where you're dispatching the action to fetch data, and conditionally stop further fetching based on that value.

you're right on the second part - transactions comes through with paging data, and I render a map of transactions.data. Unfortunately, the main problem currentCache is not iterable remains.

Have you tried updating the merge function ? As i guess the error you're encountering is solely due the type of currentCache the function is getting, make sure it is an array, if not try assigning an empty array.

Also i see, you aren't returning from the merge function. You typically need to explicitly use the return statement to return a value from the function. If you don't include a return statement, the function will implicitly return undefined.

According to the documentation Since this is wrapped with Immer, you may either mutate the currentCacheValue directly, or return a new value, but not both at once. I believe the original example currentCache.push mutates the value directly and as such doesn't require a return statement. The modification I tried uses return. Also, merge Will only be called if the existing currentCacheData is not undefined - on first response, the cache entry will just save the response data directly.
